# Creating a OS X El Capitan bootable installer on a MacBook Pro to reinstall a MacBook Air

Tags: usb, startup, install, bootable-disk

Is it possible to create a bootable USB installer on a MacBook Pro and use it to install macOS on a MacBook Air?

For example, I'd like to use a MacBook Pro to create a bootable USB installer for El Capitan and install it on a MacBook Air that has no system on it since it's been erased completely.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. You may use macOS Recovery to reinstall El Capitan on the MacBook Air. Just turn on the MacBook Air and immediately press and hold Option-Command-R. Note that for this to work, the MacBook Air must be able to connect to the Internet. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 for more information.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos